# Wrap and indent text using coreutils

Tags: text-processing, make, text-formatting, coreutils, fold

#### Short version

I would like to create a tabular display of multiline text, similar to the following:

```
all       Build all targets
document  Create documentation of source files in the subfolders
          `src` and `script`, and write it to `man`
test      Run unit tests
```

At the moment, my input for this looks as follows, but this can of course be changed:

```
all---Build all targets
document---Create documentation of source files in the subfolders `src` and `script`, and write it to `man`
test---Run unit tests
```

I’ve tried achieving this with a combination of `awk` and `wrap`/`pr` but while the line wrapping works, the indentation doesn’t. Here’s my current approach:

```bash
…
| awk -F '---' "{ printf '%-10s %s\n', $1, $2 }" \
| fold -w $(($COLUMNS - 1)) -s
```

It generates the output

```
all       Build all targets
document  Create documentation of source files in the subfolders
`src` and `script`, and write it to `man`
test      Run unit tests
```

… in other words, the third line isn’t indented as intended.

**How can I format the text with a given wrap length and a given hanging indent width?** — Without changing anything else about the text. Bonus: this should work with UTF-8 and escape/control characters.

---

#### Background info

The goal is to create [self-documenting Makefiles](https://gist.github.com/klmr/575726c7e05d8780505a). As a consequence, the logic to format and display the code should be small, self-contained, and not rely on separately installed software; ideally, it should work on any system that can execute Makefiles, hence my restriction to (something close to) coreutils.

That said, I briefly tried solving the problem using `groff` but this became too complex very quickly (and OS X `groff` is and old version that doesn’t seem to support UTF-8).

The *original string* that I’m trying to parse and format therefore looks rather as follows:

```makefile
## Build all targets
all: test document

## Run unit tests
test:
    ./run-tests .

## create documentation of source files in the subfolders `src` and `script`,
## and write it to `man`
document:
    ${MAKE} -C src document
    ${MAKE} -C script document
```

At the moment, this is parsed using a `sed` script (see link for details) that ignores multiline comments, before being fed to the formatting code posted above.

Comment: You should be able to write the whole script in awk (sed and fold do not really add to the solution).

Comment: @ThomasDickey Can `awk` easily wrap lines at whitespace? the regular expression and text manipulation tools of `awk` are rather primitive … short of manually implementing the word-wrapping inside a (nested) loop.

Comment: awk can compute a length, determine the place to split a line and format a continuation line.  Those are easier to do than sed and wrap (and if I were writing this sort of application, would make it more portable than you propose).

Comment: @ThomasDickey Replacing `sed` by `awk` is of course possible but (a) I need to have two separate commands because I sort the entries in-between parsing and formatting, and POSIX `awk` doesn’t have built-in `sort` (gawk does); and (b) simply extracting the documentation seems simpler in `sed` than `awk`.

Comment: `sort` is not mentioned in the question..

Comment: @ThomasDickey That’s why I’m mentioning it in the comments now. It *is* mentioned in the link which I referred to when discussing `sed`. I had assumed you had read that since you were confident that `sed` wasn’t needed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With gnu awk you can do something simple like this:

```
awk -F '---' '
{ gsub(/.{50,60} /,"&\n           ",$2)
  printf "%-10s %s\n", $1, $2 }'
```

For a more accurate long-winded version handling long words:

```
awk -F '---' '
{ printf "%-10s ", $1
  n = split($2,x," ")
  len = 11
  for(i=1;i<=n;i++){
   if(len+length(x[i])>=80){printf "\n           "; len = 11}
   printf "%s ",x[i]
   len += 1+length(x[i])
  }
  printf "\n"
}'
```

Comment: This is almost perfect. The only problem is that the lower bound — 50 — is arbitrary and will break if the input contains a word with more than 10 characters at the crucial position. Any suggestion for how to fix this? Using a lower number won’t work because then the match seems to happen non-greedily (actually I’m not sure what’s happening because it’s not simply matching single words).

Comment: Yes long words are a problem for this simple code. I added some more laborious handling for better results.

Comment: Ah hm. I was precisely trying to avoid that and use a pre-baked solution instead to handle edge cases properly: for instance, the above doesn’t handle dashes nicely — but, it turns out, neither does `fold`. So I’ll go with this.

Comment: I believe that this is not specific to GNU AWK, testing it on a fresh FreeBSD installation with no GNU utilities, I get the desired output.

Answer (score 6):

After the fold command pipe the output to sed and replace the start of line with a tab. And you can control the indent with with the 'tabs ' command prior:

```
tabs 5
echo "A very long line that I want to fold on the word boundary and indent as well" | fold -s -w 20  | sed -e "s|^|\t|g"
```

```
     A very long line
     that I want to fold
     on the word
     boundary and indent
     as well
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a shorter answer that uses fold then shifts its output by 11 spaces.
To see what it is doing add a `-v` or `-x` to the final bash.

```
| sed 's:\(.*\)---\(.*\):printf "%-10s " "\1";fold -w '$(($COLUMNS - 11))' -s <<\\!|sed "1!s/^/           /"\n\2\n!\n:' | bash
```